# Why does a insertion/extraction operator's overloaded function need ostream/istream argument?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

Consider the following code with overloaded insertion & extraction operators.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CTest
{
    string d_name;
public:
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, CTest & test);
    friend istream & operator>>(istream & in, CTest & test);
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, CTest & test)
{
    out << "Name: " << test.d_name;
    return out;
}

istream & operator>>(istream & in, CTest & test)
{
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    string name;
    if(in >> name)
        test.d_name = name;

    return in;
}

int main()
{
    CTest test;
    cin >> test;   // (1)
    cout << test;  // (2)
}
```

Following the question, what's the significance of arguments ostream & out and istream & in?
Since we can see only one argument (cin >> test or cout << test), where in the caller is the ostream/istream references passed at (1) or (2)?

Comment: There's two arguments in `cin >> test`.

Comment: `istream` isn't a synonym for `cin`, it's its type.

Comment: If you don't pass a stream to your `operator` how should the function know to which stream it should write the data to or from which stream ist should read it? The _streaming operators_ are designed to work with any stream (std in and out, file stream, network streams, user defined streams, ...). So the question should be how do those operator functions get two arguments.

Comment: Your *insertion operator* (`<<`) should take const ref: `CTest const& test`.

Comment: My doubt is - for a function the parameters are passed in parenthesis, for e.g - fn(p1, p2); But here I'm unable to comprehend the design of this function where the parameters are passed unconventionally. cout(parameter 1) << test(parameter 2).

Comment: Read about “operator overloading”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in both `cin >> test` and `cout << test`, two arguments exist.

`cin` is of type `istream`.

`cout` is of type `ostream`.

These types could be other things than `cout` and `cin`. For example, they could be `cerr`, `clog`, or `stringstream`.

That's why you need two arguments, since the one is the variable for the stream and the other is the object to be streamed.

Comment: Other `istream`s and `ostream`s can include file streams, `cerr`, `clog` (though it's rare to use that one), and `stringstream`s. That's all I can think of in the standard library, but I might be missing some, and other libraries like Boost implement their own.

Comment: @gsamaras
I'm unable to comprehend the design of this function that takes arguments in this unconventional way.
Could you throw some light on it, please?

Comment: @Rahul for example, the `<<` operator you have, can write `test.d_name` into either `cout` or `cerr`. You want to have this flexibility, because now you can write (`cout << test` and `cerr << test`). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I understand that use of istream/ostream for the sake of convinience to achieve the same with cerr, etc.

My doubt is - for a function the parameters are passed in parenthesis, for e.g - fn(p1, p2);
But here I'm unable to comprehend the design of this function where the parameters are passed unconventionally. cout(parameter 1) << test(parameter 2).

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> test;
```

Here, left operand is the `cin` object of type `std::istream`, and the right operand is your `CTest` class object.

Prototype of `>>` operator

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& s, Your class &);
```

So, internally we have passed two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a better understanding where the two arguments come from, you may rewrite your main() function as follows:

```
int main()
{
    CTest test;
    operator>>(std::cin, test);
    operator<<(std::cout, test);
}
```